# Rotate four div on click

Tags: jquery

I have four DIVs as A,B,C and D in order, each DIV has an up/down button. When it is being clicked the DIV Should replace position. E.g if up in the B DIV is being clicked the order should be B, A, C and D.

Comment: Post some code of what you already tried.

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: This is not the place where you say I want this do for me .. Its a place where you can get hint to solve your problems. !! show us what you have done so far and what problem you are getting. then only we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this,[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9RDKV/)

CSS

```
    .myDiv{
        clear: both;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        margin-left: 20px;
    }
```

HTML CODE

```
<body>
    <div class="myDiv">
        A
        <button type="button" class="up">UP</button>
        <button type="button" class="down">DOWN</button>
    </div>
    <div class="myDiv">
        B
        <button type="button" class="up">UP</button>
        <button type="button" class="down">DOWN</button>
    </div>
    <div class="myDiv">
        C
        <button type="button" class="up">UP</button>
        <button type="button" class="down">DOWN</button>
    </div>
    <div class="myDiv">
        D
        <button type="button" class="up">UP</button>
        <button type="button" class="down">DOWN</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
 $(function(){
        $('.up').click(function(){
            var div = $(this).parent();
            if(div.prev().length){
                $(div.prev() ).before(div);
            }
        })
        $('.down').click(function(){
                var div = $(this).parent();
                if(div.next().length){
                    $(div.next()).after(div);
                }
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

My **Assumption** may help you,

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="a" class="cont"> A </div>
    <div id="b" class="cont"> B </div>
    <div id="c" class="cont"> C </div>
    <div id="c" class="cont"> D </div>  
</div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click','.cont',function(){
        $clone=$(this).clone();
        $(this).remove();
        $('#container').prepend($clone);
    });
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g6X9j/)** and **[Fiddle with some animation](http://jsfiddle.net/g6X9j/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

working section up/down full code here with up and down button or live demo on  ([**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/H8ugH/1/))

### html code:

```
<div class="section a">
    <a class="up">UP</a>
    <a class="down">Down</a>  
</div>
<div class="section b">
    <a class="up">UP</a>
    <a class="down">Down</a>  
</div>
<div class="section c">
    <a class="up">UP</a>
    <a class="down">Down</a>  
</div>
<div class="section d">
    <a class="up">UP</a>
    <a class="down">Down</a>  
</div>
```

### css code:

```
.section{width:500px; color:#fff; font-family:arial; margin-bottom:10px; text-align:center; font-size:30px;}
.a{background-color:#09F; height:50px; line-height:50px;}
.b{background-color:#333; height:100px; line-height:100px;}
.c{background-color:#9C3; height:150px; line-height:150px;}
.d{background-color:#F93; height:200px; line-height:200px;}

a{display:inline-block; margin: 0 10px; text-decoration:underline; cursor:pointer;}
a:hover{text-decoration:none;}
```

### jQuery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

  $(".section a").click(function(e){
       var eSection = $(this).parent('.section');
      if($(e.target).is('.up') && eSection.prev('.section').length) {
          eSection.prev('.section').insertAfter(eSection);
      }

      if($(e.target).is('.down') && eSection.next('.section').length) {
          eSection.next('.section').insertBefore(eSection);
      }

  });

});
```